# android: service with null intent

Tags: android

I have a widget that updates through a service whose onStart() references an Intent.  After a period of using other applications, it seems as if the Android system restarts the service, presumably in some resource management capacity, leaving this intent null.  In my onStart(), I am checking for null intent:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){

    if(intent != null){
       //do stuff

     } else {
        System.out.println("service restarted");
    }
```

}

But I am getting a nullPointerException on the conditional statement.

What is the correct way of dealing with this?  The service is run from an alarm once per hour, so all it needs to do is run updateAppWidget when the system restarts it (I think...), but I'm not sure how to avoid this null pointer.

Comment: Why dont you try to use onStartCommand() in you service instead?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski and return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY

Answer (score 0):

check whether  did you pass a value on `putString()` if not means it throws null pointer exceptions.